# Having trouble resolving a subversion 1.8.8 "make check test" - FAIL: wc_tests.py 7: inaccessible .svn/wc.db

Tags: python, svn

I'm preparing to "make install" Subversion 1.8.8 on a centos 5.9 box using the following prerequisites:

Apr-Util-1.5.3
SQLite-3.8.4.1
OpenSSL-1.0.1f
Serf-1.3.4
Python 2.7.6 (also have the default Python 2.4 installed)

I was able to "make" just fine.  But, I keep getting 1 fail error on test 96/96 on wc_tests.py (specifically wc_tests.py 7) when running a "make check".  Below is sample of what i get when i try to run a test on the file in question:

```
# make check TESTS=subversion/tests/cmdline/wc_tests.py
[1/1] wc_tests.py........................................................FAILURE
At least one test was SKIPPED, checking /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/tests.log
SKIP:  wc_tests.py 11: missing .svn/wc.db and .svn/entries
At least one test XFAILED, checking /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/tests.log
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 1: file status through unversioned symlink
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 2: file status through versioned symlink
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 3: file status with not-parent symlink
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 4: add file through unversioned symlink
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 5: add file through versioned symlink
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 6: add file with not-parent symlink
At least one test FAILED, checking /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/tests.log
FAIL:  wc_tests.py 7: inaccessible .svn/wc.db
Summary of test results:
6 tests PASSED
1 test SKIPPED
6 tests XFAILED
1 test FAILED
SUMMARY: Some tests failed.
```

...and here is my log file:

```
START: wc_tests.py
W: Couldn't find node 'wc_tests-1' in actual status tree
W:  * Node name:   wc_tests-1
  Path:       svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-1
  Contents:   None
  Properties: {}
  Attributes: {'status': '  ', 'wc_rev': '1'}
  Children:  None (node is probably a file)

W: ACTUAL STATUS TREE:
svntest.wc.State(wc_dir, {})
W: CWD: /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline
W: EXCEPTION: SVNTreeUnequal
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 1550, in run
  rc = self.pred.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 114, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 254, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 176, in run
  return self.func(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/wc_tests.py", line 61, in status_through_unversioned_symlink
  svntest.actions.run_and_verify_status(sbox.ospath('Z/mu'), state)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/actions.py", line 1479, in run_and_verify_status
  status_tree.compare_and_display('status', actual_status)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/wc.py", line 338, in compare_and_display
  default_singleton_handler('actual ' + label, path, norm_self.desc[path])
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/wc.py", line 1048, in default_singleton_handler
  raise svntest.tree.SVNTreeUnequal
SVNTreeUnequal
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 1: file status through unversioned symlink
W: Couldn't find node 'wc_tests-2' in actual status tree
W:  * Node name:   wc_tests-2
  Path:       svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-2
  Contents:   None
  Properties: {}
  Attributes: {'status': '  ', 'wc_rev': '1'}
  Children:  None (node is probably a file)

W: ACTUAL STATUS TREE:
svntest.wc.State(wc_dir, {})
W: CWD: /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline
W: EXCEPTION: SVNTreeUnequal
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 1550, in run
  rc = self.pred.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 114, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 254, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 176, in run
  return self.func(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/wc_tests.py", line 74, in status_through_versioned_symlink
  svntest.actions.run_and_verify_status(sbox.ospath('Z/mu'), state)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/actions.py", line 1479, in run_and_verify_status
  status_tree.compare_and_display('status', actual_status)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/wc.py", line 338, in compare_and_display
  default_singleton_handler('actual ' + label, path, norm_self.desc[path])
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/wc.py", line 1048, in default_singleton_handler
  raise svntest.tree.SVNTreeUnequal
SVNTreeUnequal
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 2: file status through versioned symlink
W: Couldn't find node 'wc_tests-3' in actual status tree
W:  * Node name:   wc_tests-3
  Path:       svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-3
  Contents:   None
  Properties: {}
  Attributes: {'status': '  ', 'wc_rev': '1'}
  Children:  None (node is probably a file)

W: ACTUAL STATUS TREE:
svntest.wc.State(wc_dir, {})
W: CWD: /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline
W: EXCEPTION: SVNTreeUnequal
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 1550, in run
  rc = self.pred.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 114, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 254, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 176, in run
  return self.func(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/wc_tests.py", line 85, in status_with_symlink_in_path
  svntest.actions.run_and_verify_status(sbox.ospath('Z/B/lambda'), state)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/actions.py", line 1479, in run_and_verify_status
  status_tree.compare_and_display('status', actual_status)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/wc.py", line 338, in compare_and_display
  default_singleton_handler('actual ' + label, path, norm_self.desc[path])
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/wc.py", line 1048, in default_singleton_handler
  raise svntest.tree.SVNTreeUnequal
SVNTreeUnequal
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 3: file status with not-parent symlink
W: svn: E150000: Can't find parent directory's node while trying to add '/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-4/Z/kappa'
W: svn: E155010: The node '/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-4/Z' was not found.
W: CWD: /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline
W: EXCEPTION: Failure: Command failed: "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/svn/svn add svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-4/Z/kappa --config-dir ..."; exit code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 1550, in run
  rc = self.pred.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 114, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 254, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 176, in run
  return self.func(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/wc_tests.py", line 96, in add_through_unversioned_symlink
  sbox.simple_add('Z/kappa')
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/sandbox.py", line 266, in simple_add
  svntest.main.run_svn(False, 'add', *targets)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 682, in run_svn
  *(_with_auth(_with_config_dir(varargs))))
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 365, in run_command
  None, *varargs)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 557, in run_command_stdin
  '"; exit code ' + str(exit_code))
Failure: Command failed: "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/svn/svn add svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-4/Z/kappa --config-dir ..."; exit code 1
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 4: add file through unversioned symlink
W: svn: E145001: Can't schedule an addition of '/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-5/Z/kappa' below a not-directory node
W: CWD: /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline
W: EXCEPTION: Failure: Command failed: "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/svn/svn add svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-5/Z/kappa --config-dir ..."; exit code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 1550, in run
  rc = self.pred.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 114, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 254, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 176, in run
  return self.func(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/wc_tests.py", line 108, in add_through_versioned_symlink
  sbox.simple_add('Z/kappa')
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/sandbox.py", line 266, in simple_add
  svntest.main.run_svn(False, 'add', *targets)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 682, in run_svn
  *(_with_auth(_with_config_dir(varargs))))
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 365, in run_command
  None, *varargs)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 557, in run_command_stdin
  '"; exit code ' + str(exit_code))
Failure: Command failed: "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/svn/svn add svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-5/Z/kappa --config-dir ..."; exit code 1
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 5: add file through versioned symlink
W: svn: warning: W155010: The node '/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-6/Z' was not found.
W: svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist
W: svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
W: CWD: /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline
W: EXCEPTION: Failure: Command failed: "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/svn/svn add svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-6/Z/B/kappa --config-dir ..."; exit code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 1550, in run
  rc = self.pred.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 114, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 254, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 176, in run
  return self.func(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/wc_tests.py", line 119, in add_with_symlink_in_path
  sbox.simple_add('Z/B/kappa')
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/sandbox.py", line 266, in simple_add
  svntest.main.run_svn(False, 'add', *targets)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 682, in run_svn
  *(_with_auth(_with_config_dir(varargs))))
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 365, in run_command
  None, *varargs)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 557, in run_command_stdin
  '"; exit code ' + str(exit_code))
Failure: Command failed: "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/svn/svn add svn-test-work/working_copies/wc_tests-6/Z/B/kappa --config-dir ..."; exit code 1
XFAIL: wc_tests.py 6: add file with not-parent symlink
W: Status when wc.db is not accessible
W: EXPECTED STDERR (regexp):
W: | [^ ]+ E155016: The working copy database at '.*' is corrupt
W: ACTUAL STDERR:
W: CWD: /home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline
W: EXCEPTION: SVNUnmatchedError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/main.py", line 1550, in run
  rc = self.pred.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 254, in run
  return self._delegate.run(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/testcase.py", line 176, in run
  return self.func(sandbox)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/wc_tests.py", line 131, in status_with_inaccessible_wc_db
  "st", sbox.wc_dir)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/actions.py", line 282, in run_and_verify_svn
  expected_exit, *varargs)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/actions.py", line 321, in run_and_verify_svn2
  verify.verify_outputs(message, out, err, expected_stdout, expected_stderr)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/verify.py", line 445, in verify_outputs
  compare_and_display_lines(message, label, expected, actual, raisable)
File "/home/cprdev/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/tests/cmdline/svntest/verify.py", line 418, in compare_and_display_lines
  raise raisable
SVNUnmatchedError
FAIL:  wc_tests.py 7: inaccessible .svn/wc.db
PASS:  wc_tests.py 8: corrupt .svn/wc.db
PASS:  wc_tests.py 9: zero-length .svn/wc.db
PASS:  wc_tests.py 10: missing .svn/wc.db
SKIP:  wc_tests.py 11: missing .svn/wc.db and .svn/entries
PASS:  wc_tests.py 12: missing .svn/wc.db, maybe valid .svn/entries
PASS:  wc_tests.py 13: cleanup from directory below WC root
PASS:  wc_tests.py 14: update through unversioned symlink
END: wc_tests.py
ELAPSED: wc_tests.py 0:00:01.729278
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've learned:

I was running the tests as root which gave me access to the file and causes the test to fail. It's generally a bad idea to build software or run tests as root, you generally only need root access when you get to the install step.

Comment: I had the same error in the check #96 and used user root as builder. Then I used a non-privileged user to compile and run tests... Now the 96 tests are SUCCESSFUL but the summary of checks are: Summary of test results:
  1926 tests PASSED
  55 tests SKIPPED
  30 tests XFAILED (1 WORK-IN-PROGRESS)
SUMMARY: All tests successful.